# Setting property value of object in a deep javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, find, lodash

I was wondering if anyone could help figure out how i can set the value of a property in an object which can be found in a deep Array.

Below is an example of the Tree array

I would like to know how i can insert

```
var newObjectToInsert = {id: 999, name: 'new name'};
```

in the 'nodes' array of the object whose id === 3901

```js
var tree = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Level 1 - A',
    nodes: [
      {
        id: 33,
        name: 'Level 2 = A',
        nodes: []
      },
      
      {
        id: 21,
        name: 'Level 2 = B',
        nodes: []
      }
    ]
  },
  
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Level 1 - B',
    nodes: []
  },
  
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Level 1 - B',
    nodes: [
      {
        id: 65,
        name: 'Level 2 = A',
        nodes: []
      },

      {
        id: 124,
        name: 'Level 2 = A',
        nodes: [
          {
            id: 3901,
            name: 'Level 3 - A'
          },
          
          {
            id: 29182,
            name: 'Level 3 - B',
            nodes: [
              {
                id: 32423413,
                name: 'Level 4 - A'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
  
      {
        id: 534,
        name: 'Level 2 = A',
        nodes: []
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a native [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to achieve a recursive traversal. An advantage towards using this approach is it already provides a mechanism to stop the traversal once it finds the node that we want to insert the new object.

```
var inserted = tree.some(function cb(v) {
  var nodes = v.nodes || [];
  return v.id === nodeId?
    (v.nodes = nodes).push(newObjectToInsert):
    nodes.some(cb);
});
```

```js
var tree = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Level 1 - A',
    nodes: [{
        id: 33,
        name: 'Level 2 = A',
        nodes: []
      },

      {
        id: 21,
        name: 'Level 2 = B',
        nodes: []
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Level 1 - B',
    nodes: []
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Level 1 - B',
    nodes: [{
        id: 65,
        name: 'Level 2 = A',
        nodes: []
      },

      {
        id: 124,
        name: 'Level 2 = A',
        nodes: [{
            id: 3901,
            name: 'Level 3 - A'
          },

          {
            id: 29182,
            name: 'Level 3 - B',
            nodes: [{
              id: 32423413,
              name: 'Level 4 - A'
            }]
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        id: 534,
        name: 'Level 2 = A',
        nodes: []
      }
    ]
  },
];

var newObjectToInsert = {id: 999, name: 'new name'};
var nodeId = 3901;

var inserted = tree.some(function cb(v) {
  var nodes = v.nodes || [];
  return v.id === nodeId?
    (v.nodes = nodes).push(newObjectToInsert):
    nodes.some(cb);
});

console.log(tree);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge. This works a treat and best of all, i have learnt something new! I knew i needed a recursive function but wasn't sure what the best way was. I have implemented this method and it works brilliantly @ryeballar

Comment: @MolikMiah, note that you can also use [_.some](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#some) as an alternative, if you're concerned about old browser versions that doesn't implement `Array#some`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a recursive structure. So you visit all items you need a visitor.

Pseudo code:

```
function visit(visitor, tree) {
  visitor(tree);
  items.nodes.forEach(subTree => visit(visitor, subTree));
}
```

And use

```
visit(node => {
  if (node.id === 'whatever'){
    node.push({yournode});
  }
}, tree);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Basarat, this works a treat and it's very easy to understand :)